# Prefixing currency symbol with a background, in front of the textbox field

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have to create a text field as below:

[image]

After my quick initial changes I got to the point as below. I am less concerned about the borders but more about the background of currency symbol.

[image]

Code (I had to modify the snippet to work in online tool):

```css
.currencySpan {
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
    left: -160px;
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.currencyText {
    padding-left: 40px;
    display: inline;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="icon-addon addon-md" style="vertical-align:top;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="0.00" class="form-control currencyText" id="paymentAmount">
            <span class="currencySpan">$</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions how I can get the currency background right?

Comment: Are you allowed to use any library? If yes, Bootstrap has readymade solution for you. If no, then I can suggest some code http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: @BikasVaibhav I am using angular UI which has a bootstrap implementation (I think). Your link helped!! If you can create a response I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Added the answer with both Bootstrap and pure CSS solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap implementation for input groups. See the link
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Alternatively, if you want to do pure CSS way, you can see this bin

http://jsbin.com/xaqeheyini/edit?html,css,output